# Java - hashCode() in Integer variable returning the assigned value

Tags: java, hashcode

Hi I'm just trying to understand some basics concepts like `immutable` in `java` programming. So I came across this coding.

```
public class IntImmutable {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Integer i = 10;
      System.out.println("value = "+i " hashCode = "+i.hashCode())
      i+=9;
      System.out.println("value = "+i " hashCode = "+i.hashCode())
  }
}
```

Here I understand the code concept `immutable` but the value `hashCode()` returning is weird. Here is the output

```
value = 10 hashCode = 10
value = 19 hashCode = 19
```

If you notice the value and `hashCode` value is same, is it the expected 
behavior, My understand is `hashCode` would return some `memory reference value`.

Comment: It returns a memory reference for Object.  That wouldn't be very useful behaviour for Integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hashcode is fine, as it is returning a value consistent with the [contract for hashCode.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--)

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.

Yes, that works. The reassignment of `i` creates a new Integer object so the hashcode can differ.

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

Making the hashcode just the integer value is an easy way to do this. If `equals(anotherInteger)` returns true, then the two integers have the same value. An easy way for the hashcodes to be the same value is for the hashcodes to be just those integers.

> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

This does happen, because the set of possible `Integer` values is the same as the set of possible hashcodes. The way the hash code is implemented for `java.lang.Integer` makes a trivial one-to-one mapping between the two sets.

`i+=9` is assigning a *new* instance of `java.lang.Integer` to `i` than was before. First, `i` is unboxed to a primitive value of 10, 9 is added to that value to reach 19, and then it is re-boxed into a *different* `Integer` object. Run the following code:

```
Integer i = 10;
Integer j = 10;
System.out.println("value = " + i + " hashCode = " + i.hashCode());
System.out.println("value = " + j + " hashCode = " + j.hashCode());
i += 9;
System.out.println("value = " + i + " hashCode = " + i.hashCode());
System.out.println("value = " + j + " hashCode = " + j.hashCode());
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `Integer.hashCode()` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode%28%29):

> Returns:
>      a hash code value for this object, **equal to the primitive int value represented by this Integer object**.

The `hashCode()` contract states that it must return an integer value such that:

> If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

As we can see, the implementation of `Integer.hashCode()` satisfies this condition.

Comment: I'm interested to know why this is. A hashmap containing many small integers might have performance issue as many of them might end up in the same bucket.

Comment: @hexafraction Not a `java.util.HashMap` because it takes care to disperse the hashcode bits.

Comment: @hexafraction However, the old `Hashtable` does suffer from this. People usually only stress its being synchronized as the primary issue, but actually many use cases would suffer more from the bad hashing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, may I know the meaning behind `it takes care to disperse the hashCode bits`

Comment: HashMap doesn't directly use the hash code as supplied by the `hashCode()` method. It performs some bitwise transformations on it in order to make all the bits equally variable between different objects. This is to avoid problems with hashcodes of similar magnitude, such as in a set of smallish `Integer` instances.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the hashcode is calculated from the Integer class itself.
For pure hashcode of a particular object use following code.

`System.identityHashCode(obj)`